# Angular CLI build error with options --prod and --aot

Tags: angular, command-line-interface, angular-cli, serve

thanks for reading my question.
Now, i'm a application build in Angular CLI.
This is my package.json:

```
{
"@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/cdk": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/flex-layout": "*",
"@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/material": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/platform-server": "^4.4.4",
"@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
"angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.3.0",
"angular2-json-schema-form": "*",
"angular2-toaster": "*",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"ng2-responsive": "*",
"rxjs": "^5.5.2",
"socket.io-client": "^1.3.0",
"systemjs": "0.19.40",
"traceur": "*",
"zone.js": "^0.8.14"
```

}

In my application, i have some select tag like:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-auto" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-auto-tab">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="mb-2 schema-form-div list-group-item form-group col-md-12" *ngFor="let choice of autoRestartScheduleField; let idx = index;">
          <div class="row">
            <label for="cluster" class="m-auto col-md-1">Cluster </label>
            <select class="p-0 m-auto col-md-4 form-control" name="cluster" id="cluster" [(ngModel)]="autoRestartScheduleField[idx].cluster" (change)="onSelectClusterChange(idx)">
              <option *ngFor="let cls of listClusterCanChoice" value="{{cls.cluster}}" [disabled]="cls.hide">{{cls.cluster}}</option>
            </select>
            <label for="timer" class="m-auto col-md-1">Timer </label>
            <input class="m-auto col-md-1 form-control" name="timer" id="timer" [(ngModel)]="autoRestartScheduleField[idx].timer" type="number">
            <label for="type" class="m-auto col-md-1">Type </label>
            <select class="p-0 m-auto col-md-2 form-control" name="type" id="type" [(ngModel)]="autoRestartScheduleField[idx].type">
              <option class="mat-select" value="hour">hour</option>
              <option class="mat-select" value="day">day</option>
              <option class="mat-select" value="week">week</option>
            </select>
            <button class="mr-3 col-md-1 btn btn-warning" (click)="removeField(idx)">Delete</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="addNewField()">New</button>
          <button class="ml-3 btn btn-primary" (click)="autoRestartOnSubmit()">Save!</button>
        </div>

      </div>
  </div>
```

I using twoway binding and (change) to handler event when i select some value.
So, when i run this with "ng server", my application like this (this is result that i want):
[Run my application with "ng serve" version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sf9aT.gif)

But, when i build the application with cammand "ng build --prod --aot", then i run this on express server, i receive result (i don't know why that happend???):
[Run my application with "ng build --prod --aot" version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4010.gif)

However, i build again with command "ng build" without opts and run it on my express server, i receive result that like when i run "ng serve".
[Run my application with "ng build" without opts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sf9aT.gif)

I don't why that happen. I thing i break something when run "ng build --prod --oat" but i don't receive any warning or error.

Thanks again and happy new year!

Comment: I thing when i build with "ng build --prod --aot" make my aplication when hadler (change) event and [(ngModel)].

Comment: Have you tried running without aot ? was that successfull ? aot needs a different setup, you need to do certain stuff to enable it at first place